# Is this a strong reference cycle or memory leak at all?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, strong-references

The examples about strong reference cycles I usually see involve two classes with properties pointing to each other. However, what if only one of the classes has a property pointing to the other instance like this:

```
class ClassA {
    var classB: ClassB? = nil
}

class ClassB {

}
```

Then I create my instances like this:

```
var myClassA = ClassA()
var myClassB = ClassB() //Reference count 1
myClassA.classB = myClassB //Reference count 2

// Now deallocate
myClassB = nil  //Reference count 1
myClassA = nil
```

Since I've deallocated `myClassB`, the reference count is 1. What happened to the reference count of `myClassA.classB`? It never reached zero since I never did `myClassA.classB = nil` or used `deinit` to do this. Is this implicitly done since I did `myClassA = nil`?

Is this what can be categorized as a strong reference cycle? I would imagine that it is at least a memory leak though, is this true?

Comment: There is neither a leakage nor a circular reference in your code. When you set `myClassA` to `nil`, ARC automatically breaks ownership of `ClassB` so both of them get deallocated.

Comment: To expand on that — there is no cycle, since your graph only has one edge: `myClassA.classB -> myClassB`.

Comment: If that code caused a link, it would make ARC only marginally useful.  All references held at the instance level are released when the instance is released.

Comment: All of the above comments are quite right. BTW, if you add `deinit` method to both classes that prints something, you can empirically verify that the instance of `ClassA` and that of `ClassB` are both getting deallocated. Also, probably needless to say, but `myClassA` and `myClassB` both have to be defined as optionals in order to set them to `nil`.

Comment: I added an example based upon @Rob's comment to demonstrate in a Playground:  1) the original code doesn't have a strong reference cycle, 2) what it would take to create a strong reference cycle, 3) how to break that strong reference cycle.

Comment: That's a relief, thx everyone! I guess this is because of ARC, otherwise you'd have to set `myClassA.classB` to nil in ClassA's `deinit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ozgur, @jtbandes, @Avi, and @Rob explained in the comments, there is no strong reference cycle or leak.

Here is an example based upon @Rob's comment that you can run in a Playground:

```
class ClassA {
    var classB: ClassB?

    deinit {
        print("ClassA deallocated")
    }
}

class ClassB {
    deinit {
        print("ClassB deallocated")
    }
}

class Tester {
    func test() {
        var myClassA: ClassA! = ClassA()
        var myClassB: ClassB! = ClassB() //Reference count 1
        myClassA.classB = myClassB //Reference count 2

        // Now deallocate
        print("setting myClassB to nil")
        myClassB = nil  //Reference count 1
        print("setting myClassA to nil")
        myClassA = nil
        print("all done")
    }
}

// Create `Tester` object and call `test`:

Tester().test()
```

Output:

> ```
> setting myClassB to nil
> setting myClassA to nil
> ClassA deallocated
> ClassB deallocated
> all done
> ```

The thing to note is that even though you set `myClassB` to `nil` first, that `myClassA` gets freed first.  When `myClassA` gets freed, the final reference to `myClassB` is released by ARC and then `myClassB` is freed.

---

To demonstrate a strong reference cycle, have `ClassB` retain a strong reference to `ClassA`:

```
class ClassA {
    var classB: ClassB?

    deinit {
        print("ClassA deallocated")
    }
}

class ClassB {
    var classA: ClassA?

    deinit {
        print("ClassB deallocated")
    }
}

class Tester {
    func test() {
        var myClassA:ClassA! = ClassA()
        var myClassB:ClassB! = ClassB() //Reference count 1
        myClassA.classB = myClassB //Reference count 2
        myClassB.classA = myClassA

        // Now deallocate
        print("setting myClassB to nil")
        myClassB = nil  //Reference count 1
        print("setting myClassA to nil")
        myClassA = nil
        print("all done")
    }
}

Tester().test()
```

Output:

> ```
> setting myClassB to nil
> setting myClassA to nil
> all done
> ```

Neither object is deallocated if they both contain strong reference to the other.  To break this strong reference cycle, declare one of the `classB` or `classA` properties to be `weak`.  Which one you choose affects the order that the objects get freed:

If you declare `weak var classB: ClassB` in `ClassA`:

Output:

> ```
> setting myClassB to nil
> ClassB deallocated
> setting myClassA to nil
> ClassA deallocated
> all done
> ```

If instead, you declare `weak var classA: ClassA in ClassB`:

Output:

> ```
> setting myClassB to nil
> setting myClassA to nil
> ClassA deallocated
> ClassB deallocated
> all done
> ```